# HTTPS certificates don't work after generation with openssl

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, esp32, esp-idf

I ran the Espressif HTTPS Server [example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/https_server/simple), with the provided [certificates](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/https_server/simple/main/certs). I was able to successfully connect to the server accepting the warning in my browser (as expected).

Then, following the instructions contained in the above README file I issued in the `certs` folder:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout prvtkey.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out cacert.pem -subj "/CN=My own certificate"
```

and uploaded the new firmware to the ESP32.
Now, I can't connect anymore. Firefox says:

> SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE

while Chrome says:

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

on server side I get the following messages:

```
E (1059558) esp-tls-mbedtls: mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x7780
E (1059558) esp_https_server: esp_tls_create_server_session failed
E (1059558) httpd: httpd_accept_conn: session creation failed
W (1059568) httpd: httpd_server: error accepting new connection
```

I RFTM and followed their instruction. What could prevent the creation of the secure connection with the certificate I generate using `openssl`?

Both certificates (mine and those provided by Expressif) are equal in lengths and headers.

Comment: I'm guessing that somehow your public key in your certificate and your private key are not from the same keypair. I don't know how that can happen since I don't know the steps you performed to get your newly generated keys onto the ESP32.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it's described in the question. I `cd` into the folder where the certificates are and I replaced them issuing the `openssl` command, then I built and programmed the firmware on the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comment of user President James K. Polk, I went deeper about the files generated by `openssl` and I discovered that the official docs of Expressif are **wrong**.

The README reports:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout prvtkey.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out cacert.pem -subj "/CN=ESP32 HTTPS server example"
```

but the CMakeLists.txt of the project contains:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "main.c"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS "."
                    EMBED_TXTFILES "certs/servercert.pem"
                                   "certs/prvtkey.pem")
```

in fact, also the [cert](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/https_server/simple/main/certs) directories contains those files.
Hence `openssl` created `cacert.pem` instead of `servercert.pem`.

The right command to issue is:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout prvtkey.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out servercert.pem -subj "/CN=ESP32 HTTPS server example"
```

This leads to the expected behavior.